# Flutter BloC Pattern: Update BloC Streams Based Another BloC's Stream

Tags: dart, flutter, bloc

**SCENARIO**

I'm trying to create a Flutter app that has two screens: `ContactsScreen` and `EditContactScreen`. In `ContactsScreen`, the user will be presented with a `DropdownButton` and `Text`. The `DropdownButton` holds a list of `Contact` objects that have been fetched through an api. Whenever a user selects a `Contact` from the `DropdownButton`, the `Text` object will show information regarding that particular contact. Moreover, upon `Contact` selection, a `RaisedButton` will appear, which when clicked, will direct the user to the `EditContactScreen` to edit the selected `Contact`. I'm using the BloC pattern. I created two BloCs, one for each screen: `ContactsScreenBloc` and `EditContactScreenBloc`. `ContactsScreenBloc` holds a `Stream<Contact>` and a `Sink<Contact>` for managing the selected `Contact`. Whereas `EditContactScreenBloc` holds streams and sinks for the `Contact` fields. Finally, I have a `GlobalBloc` that holds the list of `Contact`s. The `GlobalBloc` is an `InheritedWidget` that wraps up the `MaterialApp`. The app is oversimplified and is part of a larger one, for that reason, I can't merge `ContactsScreenBloc` and `EditContactScreenBloc`, and there should be a `GlobalBloc` that has the list of `Contact`s.

**QUESTION**

I'm actually fairly new to Flutter so I'm not sure if my approach is sound. If it is, then when the user navigates to the `EditContactScreen` and successfully updates the `Contact`, how can I reflect it back in the selected `Contact` in `ContactsScreen`?

**CODE SNIPPITS**

**contact.dart**

```
class Contact {
  final String id;
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final String phoneNumber;

  Contact({this.id, this.firstName, this.lastName, this.phoneNumber});
  Contact.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson)
        : id = parsedJson['id'],
          firstName = parsedJson['firstName'],
          lastName = parsedJson['lastName'],
          phoneNumber = parsedJson['phoneNumber'];

  copyWith({String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber}) => Contact(
    id: id,
    firstName: firstName ?? this.firstName,
    lastName: lastName ?? this.lastName,
    phoneNumber: phoneNumber ?? this.phoneNumber
  );

  @override
  bool operator ==(other) => other.id == this.id;

  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode;
}
```

**global.bloc.dart**

```
class GlobalBloc {
  final _repo = Repo();

  final _contacts = BehaviorSubject<List<Contact>>(seedValue: []);

  Stream<List<Contact>> get contacts => _contacts.stream;

  Function(List<Contact>) get updateContacts => _contacts.sink.add;

  Future refreshContacts() async{
    final contacts = await _repo.getContacts();
    updateContacts(contacts);
  }
}
```

**contacts_screen.bloc.dart**

```
class ContactsScreenBloc {
  final _selectedContact = BehaviorSubject<Contact>(seedValue: null);

  Stream<Contact> get selectedContact => _selectedContact.stream;

  Function(Contact) get changeSelectedContact => _selectedContact.sink.add;
}
```

**edit_contacts_screen.bloc.dart**

```
class ContactsScreenBloc {
  final _selectedContact = BehaviorSubject<Contact>(seedValue: null);

  Stream<Contact> get selectedContact => _selectedContact.stream;

  Function(Contact) get changeSelectedContact => _selectedContact.sink.add;
}
```

**global.provider.dart**

```
class GlobalProvider extends InheritedWidget {
  final bloc = GlobalBloc();
  static GlobalBloc of(BuildContext context) => (context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(GlobalProvider) as GlobalProvider).bloc;
  bool updateShouldNotify(_) => true;
}
```

**contacts.screen.dart**

```
class ContactsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final bloc = ContactsScreenBloc();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final globalBloc = GlobalProvider.of(context);

    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        StreamBuilder<List<Contact>>(
          stream: globalBloc.contacts,
          builder: (context, listSnapshot) {
            return StreamBuilder<Contact>(
              stream: bloc.selectedContact,
              builder: (context, itemSnapshot) {
                return DropdownButton<Contact>(
                  items: listSnapshot.data
                      ?.map(
                        (contact) => DropdownMenuItem<Contact>(
                              value: contact,
                              child: Text(contact.firstName + ' ' + contact.lastName),
                            ),
                      )
                      ?.toList(),
                  onChanged: bloc.changeSelectedContact,
                  hint: Text('Choose a contact.'),
                  value: itemSnapshot.hasData ? itemSnapshot.data : null,
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ), // end for DropdownButton StreamBuilder

        StreamBuilder<Contact>(
          stream: bloc.selectedContact,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return snapshot.hasData
                ? Row(children: <Widget>[
                Text(snapshot.data.firstName + ' ' + snapshot.data.lastName + ' ' + snapshot.data.phoneNumber),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text('Edit Contact'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) =>
                            EditContactScreen(contact: snapshot.data)));
                  },
                ),
              ],
            )
                : null;
          }, // End for text description
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**edit_contact.screen.dart**

```
class EditContactScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final bloc = EditContactScreenBloc();
  final Contact contact;

  EditContactScreen({this.contact});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final globalBloc = GlobalProvider.of(context);

    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextField(onChanged: (firstName) => bloc.updateContact(contact.copyWith(firstName: firstName))),
        TextField(onChanged: (lastName) => bloc.updateContact(contact.copyWith(firstName: lastName))),
        TextField(onChanged: (phoneNumber) => bloc.updateContact(contact.copyWith(firstName: phoneNumber))),
        RaisedButton(child: Text('Update'), onPressed: () async {
          await bloc.update();
          await globalBloc.refreshContacts();
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        },)
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: why not create a single contact bloc instead of seperating it as `contact_screen.bloc` and `edit_contacts_screen.bloc`?

Comment: @nonybrighto yeah you're right if the app was just about these screens, but as I said, this is just a snippet of a larger app where the two blocs should be separated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I was able to solve my issue:

In the `contacts_screen.bloc.dart`, I added the following method:

```
void updateContactInfo(List<Contact> contacts) {
    final contact = _selectedContact.value;
    if (contact == null) return;
    final updatedContact = contacts.firstWhere((a) => a.id == contact.id);
    if (updatedContact == null) return;
    changeSelectedContact(updatedContact);
  }
```

And updated the `StreamBuilder<List<Contact>>` for building the `DropdownButton` to be like this:

```
StreamBuilder<List<Contact>>(
  stream: globalBloc.contacts,
  builder: (context, listSnapshot) {
    bloc.updateContactInfo(listSnapshot.data);
    return StreamBuilder<Contact>(
      stream: bloc.selectedContact,
      builder: (context, itemSnapshot) {
        return DropdownButton<Contact>(
          items: listSnapshot.data
              ?.map(
                (contact) => DropdownMenuItem<Contact>(
                      value: contact,
                      child: Text(
                          contact.firstName + ' ' + contact.lastName),
                    ),
              )
              ?.toList(),
          onChanged: bloc.changeSelectedContact,
          hint: Text('Choose a contact.'),
          value: itemSnapshot.hasData ? itemSnapshot.data : null,
        );
      },
    );
  },
)
```